# How to query between dates and those with null?

Tags: mysql

```
Select area, book, sequence, accountnumber, name, address, polenumber from master
where newconnectiondate is null
  and newconnectiondate between '1950-01-01' and '2015-10-31'
```

This is my query in mysql. But it all do wrong. I want to query data using between date but it doesnt query those with null date and now I want to query between date and with null date

Comment: Use `or` instead of `and`. I.e. `where newconnectiondate is null or newconnectiondate between '1950-01-01' and '2015-10-31'`

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: WHERE some col is  x AND y is an impossible condition

Answer (score 0):

I think taht the and is messing up your result. I think that you need to check if the `newconnectiondate` `is null OR` between the dates. Like this:

```
where 
    (newconnectiondate IS NULL)
    OR
    (newconnectiondate between '1950-01-01' and '2015-10-31')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **OR** rather than using **AND**, Using **AND** gives a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

```
where newconnectiondate is null
      AND newconnectiondate between '1950-01-01' and '2015-10-31'
```

This will always return `empty result-set`.Since `newconnectiondate` can not be `null` and a `valid date` at the same time.

So try this.

```
Select area, book, sequence, accountnumber, name, address, polenumber from master
    where newconnectiondate is null
      OR newconnectiondate between '1950-01-01' and '2015-10-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both **OR** and **AND** in your query.

```
SELECT area
    ,book
    ,sequence
    ,accountnumber
    ,NAME
    ,address
    ,polenumber
FROM master
WHERE (newconnectiondate IS NULL) -- FOR NULL DATES
    OR (
        newconnectiondate BETWEEN '1950-01-01'
            AND '2015-10-31'
        ) -- FOR BETWEEN DATES
```

**suggestion ::**

in many business logics, date plays important roles, it is better to put validation of date. Either user have to enter date or put default date as per the business requirement.